# alert the value of clicked row of a table with single column

Tags: jquery

I have a table with only one column, and I want to alert the value of the clicked row.

I tried like:

```
$("#myTable").click(function () {
    let thevalue= $(this).closest("th").children('h2').val();
    alert(thevalue);
});
```

Here my table

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i><h2>pp</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr><th><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i><h2>tt</h2></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But my code print `undefined`.

the expected retult is: if I click the `pp` row sholud alert `pp`. and if I click the `tt` row sholud alert `tt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have attached the click event to the table. You need to instead bind the click event on the row and then find child element `h2` in it.

Also, `.val()` is not valid property for heading elements. Use `.text()` to find text on it

```js
$("#myTable tr").click(function () {
    let thevalue= $(this).find('h2').text();
    alert(thevalue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i><h2>pp</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr><th><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i><h2>tt</h2></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, the table is not there when I initialize the click event in jquery. I build the table dynamically, therefore the event: `$("#myTable tr")` doesn't fire

Comment: You need to use event delegation then. `$(document).on("click","#myTable tr".function(){ /* CLICK EVENT CODE HERE */}) `

Comment: It works now, in your comment toy wrote dot instad of `','`, sholud be `$(document).on("click","#myTable tr",function(){ /* CLICK EVENT CODE HERE */})` Thank you

Comment: Ah, typo there. glad you figured it out :)